# Prevent double click on a row divider triggering celldoubleclick event

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In a datagridview with rowheaders visibility set to false and allowusertoresizerow set to true, i need to prevent the celldoubleclick event to trigger if doubleclicked on the rowdivider (Toublearrow of the row resize is visible when the cursor is on the divider).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be checking the clicked area of the grid on the CellDoubleClick event itself; the logic would be to return in case rowresizetop or rowresizebottom areas are clicked and continue processing if not. Please check an example below for more details:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // get mouse coordinates
    Point mousePoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y);
    // need to use reflection here to get access to the typeInternal field value which is declared as internal
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = hitTestInfo.GetType().GetField("typeInternal", 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    string value = fieldInfo.GetValue(hitTestInfo).ToString();
    if (value.Equals("RowResizeTop") || value.Equals("RowResizeBottom"))
    {
        // one of resize areas is double clicked; stop processing here      
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // continue normal processing of the cell double click event
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: For totally different reasons, I also needed to know whether I was clicking on the resize area of a datagridview row. This worked perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Why couldn't Microsoft include values for row and column dividers in the DataGridViewHitTestType enumeration?